# What actually happens if you provide incorrect ratio of liquidity in Uniswap-like exchanges?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange

Let's say you provide 1 ETH and 1 USDT liquidity to ETH/USDT pair on Uniswap or similar exchange.

Obviously you are not supposed to do this. But what would actually happen if you do?

Would there be any consequences? Would you lose a lot of money doing this?

Or would it automatically get balanced out to 50/50 ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will lose money. Here's why - Since most liquidity pools do not have external oracles to tell them the price ratio between two assets, they rely on participants providing the correct ratio. If you were to, as you say in your example, deposit 1 USDT and 1 ETH into a ETH/USDT pool, you would effectively be stating that you value 1 ETH to be worth 1 USDT. This is obviously not the case, and an external arbitrageur would quickly provide 1 USDT to the pool in exchange for your 1 ETH (Or something close to this, in reality the external arbitrageur would not be able to trade for your full 1 ETH, as the USDT/ETH ratio and therefore price increases asymptotically as the amount of ETH in the pool goes toward 0).

So to answer your question - You'd put in 1 ETH and 1 USDT and a few seconds later you'd be left with a tiny amount of ETH and a couple USDT.

Edit: I initially read your question as starting a pool with this ratio, however the same logic goes if you contribute this ratio to an already existing pool. You wouldn't be lowering the price per ETH to 1 USDT in that pool, but would still be lowering it by some amount inversely proportional to the size of the pool nonetheless and be making some arbitrageur very happy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if you do this in an existing pool, where you have only a slight impact on the ratio, would you still only be left with a couple dollars?

Comment: In a purely theoretical implementation of a liquidity pool, you would be lowering the average price and distributing those losses that were originally concentrated into you over all participating pool members, so no. However, I could very well imagine actual implementations having features to counteract this and either reject transactions that show too large a discrepancy to the current pool ratio or somehow concentrate losses into you more heavily if you do something like this.